# Calculating bounding box of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm struggling with a simple question. I have a numpy array of the form:

```
[[[ 1152.07507324   430.84799194]
  [ 4107.82910156   413.95199585]
  [ 4127.64941406  2872.32006836]
  [ 1191.71643066  2906.11206055]]]
```

And I want to calculate the bounding box, meaning, I want to have the leftmost, topmost, rightmost and bottommost point.

This should be a correct solution

```
[[[ 1152.07507324   413.95199585]
  [ 4127.64941406   413.95199585]
  [ 4127.64941406  2906.11206055]
  [ 1152.07507324  2906.11206055]]]
```

I developed a nasty function that does the trick, but I'm very unsatisfied with it since its not really pythonic/numpyic

```
def bounding_box(iterable):
    minimum_x = min(iterable[0], key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
    maximum_x = max(iterable[0], key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
    minimum_y = min(iterable[0], key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
    maximum_y = max(iterable[0], key=lambda x:x[1])[1]

    return numpy.array([[(minimum_x, minimum_y), (maximum_x, minimum_y), (maximum_x, maximum_y), (minimum_x, maximum_y)]], dtype=numpy.float32)
```

Do you have any idea how to optimize the function above, perhaps using numpy builtins?

Comment: Why does your sample array have three levels of square brackets?  That makes it looks like a 3D array with shape (1,n,2).  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `numpy.min` and `numpy.max` builtins:

```
def bounding_box(iterable):
    min_x, min_y = numpy.min(iterable[0], axis=0)
    max_x, max_y = numpy.max(iterable[0], axis=0)
    return numpy.array([(min_x, min_y), (max_x, min_y), (max_x, max_y), (min_x, max_y)])
```

Comment: Argv.  I was working on a shorter trick to get the Cartesian product of the results, but it's the same basic idea.

Comment: `itertools.product`? Only problem is that it gives the answer in the wrong order.

Comment: But if you can get around that and still have short code, by all means, post it. I am curious :)

Comment: I was thinking of something like `c = np.array([b.min(0), b.max(0)]); list(np.broadcast(*np.ix_(*c.T)))` -- but that second part is too clever, and the order's wrong anyway.  I'd much rather do it manually like you and the OP did so that it's instantly obvious what the result is.

Comment: Save yourself a tiny bit of hassle and (1) transform `iterable` into a 2D array `iterable=iterable.squeeze()`, (2) use the `.min`/`.max` methods instead of the `np.min`/`np.max` functions. Otherwise, +1

Answer (score 3):

returns the same as previous answer but shorter and cleaner

returns 2*2 ndarray

```
def bbox(points):
    """
    [xmin xmax]
    [ymin ymax]
    """
    a = zeros((2,2))
    a[:,0] = np.min(points, axis=0)
    a[:,1] = np.max(points, axis=0)
    return a
```

Comment: Consider adding some text to your answer, to explain what you're doing here and how this is different from the already accepted answer.  Answers that are just code blobs aren't very useful.